Barycentric subdivision of affine singular simplex
I am reading barycentric subdivision of singular simplex from Algebraic Topology by Tammo tom Dieck. But I can't understand the formula (3) in the photo. I compute the case where $p=1$ and $p=2$, and it's true. But I don't know why it is true when $p$ increasing. I don't know how it is connected to $\sigma^{\beta}$(barycentric of $\sigma$). i just know how to get formula when $[v_0,\dots,v_p]=[e_0,\dots,e_p]$. I would be grateful if you could give me some hints to help me obtain the formula.

Well, it likely follows from "inductive definition $(2)$". You should show this so we can aid you

@FShrike I'm sorry I forgot to give  inductive definition (2). Now it's in the new photo.

Consider the unique affine linear map $f\colon\mathbb{R}^p\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^n$ that maps $e_p\mapsto v_p$ and hence $\iota_p^{\beta}\mapsto\sigma^{\beta}$. Naturality means that $f$ takes the singular simplex $\mathcal{B}\iota_p=\mathcal{B}[e_0,\dotsc,e_p]$ to the singular simplex $\mathcal{B}[v_0,\dotsc,v_p]$, but the inductive definition says
$$\mathcal{B}\iota_p=\iota_p^{\beta}\cdot\mathcal{B}\partial\iota_p=\sum_{i=0}^p(-1)^i\iota_p^{\beta}\mathcal{B}[e_0,\dotsc,\hat{e_i},\dotsc,e_p]$$
and $f$ takes this by naturality to $\sum_{i=0}^p(-1)^i\sigma^{\beta}\cdot\mathcal{B}[v_0,\dotsc,\hat{v_i},\dotsc,v_p]$.

It's clear! Thanks a lot！
